# How to extract data from evenly spaced cells in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large amount of data that has a single column like this:

> Timestamp A
>
> (extra data for 9 rows)
>
> Timestamp B
>
> (extra data for 9 rows)
>
> Timestamp C

How do I get a column of data that would have the timestamp data all together? Like this:

> Timestamp A
>
> Timestamp B
>
> Timestamp C

I think `INDEX` can help me get there, but I couldn't figure out a formula that would get the selected row to increment by 10 when I auto-fill the column.

Comment: Are you filtering out unwanted data? It looks like that is what you are trying to do. Taking a column, take out unwanted data, and creating a new column based on data you want.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need to do. However, I can't do the old-fashioned copy and paste, as there are some 2000+ rows that I need to do this for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your end game is... would an auto filter work?  of is timestamp not really a "timestamp" thus can't be filtered?

[image]
[image]

or perhaps...

[image]

Comment: You might be going on something here. "Traditional" use of the auto-filter by clicking checkboxes on the filter list would not be practical unfortunately, as there are about 200+ data points I want. I would post an image but I don't have enough reputation points yet. The data I want is a bunch of timestamps, i.e 1:20, 1:22, 1:23, that all have the same number of rows in between them. I'm looking into the Advanced Filter option, which might help. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Could add a formula column and fill down which puts a 1 in or 0 in the results which are timestamps and then filter on it example: =IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A2))="D",1,0)